# Can't convert node without a body

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, create-react-app, react-testing-library

I'm trying to run [the example](https://github.com/kentcdodds/react-testing-library/pull/274) in `react-testing-library` to test react hooks. But it seems to fail on this line:

```
testHook(() => ({count, increment} = useCounter({ initialCount: 2 })))
```

Looks like it's related to Babel. Tried googling but cannot find anybody that seem to have the same problem. I installed webpack with `create-react-app`.

This is the stacktrace:

```
 ● Test suite failed to run

  Can't convert node without a body

  at NodePath.ensureBlock (node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/conversion.js:64:11)
  at Scope.push (node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/scope/index.js:727:12)
  at Object.toSequenceExpression (node_modules/@babel/types/lib/converters/toSequenceExpression.js:19:11)
  at NodePath.replaceExpressionWithStatements (node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/replacement.js:203:36)
  at NodePath.insertAfter (node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/modification.js:128:17)
  at NodePath.replaceWithMultiple (node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/replacement.js:85:22)
  at PluginPass.AssignmentExpression (node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring/lib/index.js:433:14)
  at newFn (node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/visitors.js:193:21)
  at NodePath._call (node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:53:20)
  at NodePath.call (node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:40:17)
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to fix the Babel issue but if you write `testHook(() => { return ({count, increment} = useCounter({ initialCount: 2 }))})`, it works. Probably they're using some advance ES6 syntax sugar that your current setup doesn't have.

Comment: @tuchi35 Yes that works for me too. If you post this as an answer I would gladly accept and upvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how to fix the Babel issue but if you write:

```
testHook(() => { return ({count, increment} = useCounter({ initialCount: 2 }))})
```

instead of:

```
testHook(() => ({count, increment} = useCounter({ initialCount: 2 })))
```

It works. Probably they're using some advance ES6 syntax sugar that your current setup doesn't have. Hope it helps!